# Raspberry Pi, RealVNC, how to change mouse cursor from an x to an arrow

Tags: raspberry-pi, mouse-cursor, realvnc

The Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian Buster and VNC Server 6.7.1. The Pi is headless.

I connect to the Pi from a Windows 10 machine via VNC Viewer 6.20.529 (r42646) x64 (May 29 2020 13:14:30).

All is well, except the Pi desktop uses an "x" cursor. Is their a way to change that to a Windows-like "arrow" cursor?

I found a recommendation to create ~/.vnc/xstartup with the line "xsetroot -solid grey -cursor_name left_ptr". I did that and rebooted the Pi, but the desktop still displays the "x" cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. All I needed to do was:

```
chmod 744 ~/.vnc/xstartup
```